# How to slide in a new loaded image on click/load

Tags: jquery, html, css, image, css-transitions

I'm having trouble figuring out how to solve this load issue. Basically I need an image, when loaded, to slide in so the load is not choppy but smooth with a transition.

This is what the stripped down version of my code looks like.

```
<div>
<img src="image1.jpg" id="mainImg" />
</div>

<div>
    <div class="clickToLoad" data-src="someCDN.com/image2.jpg"></div>
    <div class="clickToLoad" data-src="someCDN.com/image3.jpg"></div>
    <div class="clickToLoad" data-src="someCDN.com/image4.jpg"></div>
    <div class="clickToLoad" data-src="someCDN.com/image5.jpg"></div>
</div>
```

When someone clicks or swipes on one of the clickToLoad divs, the JS will take the data-src and replace it in the mainImg src of the IMG tag. These images are also being loaded from a CDN.

I also do not want to preload all the images due to page speed on a mobile device.

When they are loaded though, it just loads in. I want it to slide in from the left or right once loaded. Does anyone have any idea how to go about doing this? I've been programming for a while now and I cant seem to figure this out XD.

Please let me know,
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It took me a little bit to figure this out but I finally found a solution.

Basically, I created a new IMG element on the fly and set the positioning parameters to absolute depending on which way the person swiped. In this example, it would be a left swipe. This way, the new image loaded in, will be positioned absolutely on the right of the main image.

Once the swipe left transition is complete. It deletes the original main image, sets the dynamically created image elements ID attribute to the previous #mainImg, and we apply relative position to it so it will fill the div and be visible.

Here is my function, hopefully this helps someone else!

```
function imgL(path) {
var width = $('.mainImg').outerWidth();
var height = $('.mainImg').outerHeight();

var newImage = document.createElement('img')
newImage.src = path;
newImage.id = 'img2'
newImage.classList = 'classes';
newImage.height = height;
newImage.width = width;
newImage.style.cssText = 'position: absolute; top: 0px; left:' + width + 'px;';

$(newImage).appendTo('.mainCont');

$('.mainCont').animate({ left: -width }, 400, function () {
    $(this).css('left', '');
    $('#mainImg').remove();
    $('#img2').attr('id', 'mainImg');
    $('#mainImg').css('position', 'relative').css('left', '').attr('width', '100%').attr('draggable', 'false');
});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I composed a pseudo code and hope it can bring you some ideas.

```js
Promise.all(Array.prototype.map.apply(querySelectorAll('img'), imgEle => {
            return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                imgEle.src = this.getAttribute('data-src')
                imgEle.onload = () => {
                    resolve();
                };
                imgEle.onerror = () => {
                    reject();
                };
            });
        })).then(resArr => {
            window.scrollTo();
            //here control DOM to slide to the expected place
        })
```

```html
 <img src="" alt="" class="delay" data-src="abc11.jpg">
    <img src="" alt="" class="delay" data-src="abc21.jpg">
    <img src="" alt="" class="delay" data-src="abc31.jpg">
    <img src="" alt="" class="delay" data-src="abc41.jpg">
    <img src="" alt="" class="delay" data-src="abc51.jpg">
    <img src="" alt="" class="delay" data-src="abc61.jpg">
    <img src="" alt="" class="delay" data-src="abc71.jpg">
    <img src="" alt="" class="delay" data-src="abc81.jpg">
    <img src="" alt="" class="delay" data-src="abc91.jpg">
    <img src="" alt="" class="delay" data-src="abc101.jpg">
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer Deng, I will give this a shot tomorrow at work.